# Arabic text in Photoshop CS 3

Tags: fonts, photoshop, arabic

I want to use an arabic font & write Arabic text. I am using adobe photoshop Cs 3. I know that there used to be an option in CS 6 to enable and write arabic with ease. Is there any such option in cs 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Adobe products don't do Arabic well at all. Whenever I was working with them I always had to change my text into an image in another program to be able to do it.